# Why wont this Chapter 4 example from 'Learning Perl 6th edition' run?

Tags: perl

I am stuck on chapter 4 exercise 4 page 78 of Learning Perl 6th Edition. I copied the code example for the problem from page 301. I am using Perl version 5.10.1 on Ubuntu 11.04. I get errors that I cannot figure out could someone please help? I will list the code and the error message below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

greet( 'Fred' );
greet( 'Barney' );

sub greet {
  state $last_person;

  my $name = shift;

  print "Hi $name! ";

  if( defined $last_person ) {
      print "$last_person is also here!\n";
 }
  else {
      print "You are the first one here!\n";
}
  $last_person = $name;
}


Global symbol "$last_person" requires explicit package name at ./ex4-4 line 8.
Global symbol "$last_person" requires explicit package name at ./ex4-4 line 14.
Global symbol "$last_person" requires explicit package name at ./ex4-4 line 15.
Global symbol "$last_person" requires explicit package name at ./ex4-4 line 20.
Execution of ./ex4-4 aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Persistent-Private-Variables):

> Beginning with perl 5.9.4, you can declare variables with the state
>   keyword in place of my. For that to work, though, you must have
>   enabled that feature beforehand, either by using the feature pragma,
>   or by using -E on one-liners. (see feature)

Comment: You can also say `use 5.010` or `use 5.10.0`, which implicitly activates all the features available in that version of Perl.

Comment: Your right page 77 the last code example page before the exercises showed "use 5.010;". My program runs correctly now. I thought by using the pragma "use strict;" i was covered, but it does nothing.

Answer (score 9):

You need to say `use feature 'state'` at the top of your script to enable `state` variables. See [perldoc -f state](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html).

Comment: Or `use 5.01n;`, where n in { 0, 2, 4 }

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I should have typed in "use 5.010;" instead of "use strict;". It was in the book i got confused between the two.

Answer (score 1):

The pre-[`feature`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html) way to do it is with a closure:

```
{
    my $last_person;

    sub greet {

        my $name = shift;

        print "Hi $name! ",
          defined $last_person ? "$last_person is also here!"
                               : "You are the first one here!",
          "\n";

        $last_person = $name;
    }
}
```

---

The nifty [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#The-%27say%27-feature) feature would also be useful in this example.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. By using the pragma 'use 5.010;" as was pointed out to me above the program works. I am very intrigued by the way your code example above gets around using (if) and (else). I will definitely try that. Thank you.